# Open downloaded file (PDF) in specific program (Adobe Reader)

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, download

I create PDF files on my server (Java servlet). In the (JSP) home screen, there's a button that when clicked should have the client open the PDF file (downloaded from server) with Adobe Reader.

How to call exactly Adobe Reader to open that PDF file?

Comment: What the client does with your file is up to the client. All you can do from the server is return that file in the response and specify its MIME type ("application/pdf", for instance).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I rewrote the title of this question to clarify both what you're wanting to do a bit more grammatically, and generalize to help others with similar problems recognize that this question could help them. I also rewrote the body of the question so it would flow better, and removed a couple of essentially irrelevant tags, replacing with a somewhat more specific one.

Comment: @ NathanTuggy : thanks you.
@ AmosM.Carpenter : i did it. I think client must configure program open file pdf :)

Comment: As @Sid said, you can suggest that the client's browser should "save as" rather than directly open the document (using content-disposition), but that won't mean that Adobe Reader will open it: a) the client might be using another program as their default PDF reader (for instance, I much prefer PDF-XChange Viewer), and b) you can't control when or whether that PDF will ever be opened after it's been downloaded - that's up to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Adobe Reader as the default application to handle pdf files on the OS. Set the response HTTP header Content-Disposition this will force the browser to download the file instead of opening it within the browser. This way opening the downloaded PDF will open on Adode Reader.

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf"); 
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=downloaded.pdf");
```